# replacement has length zero in fibonacci sequence in R code

Tags: r

So I have this code for the fibonacci sequence, and I keep getting an error when I try to print out the value of the function.

```
fibonacci <- function(nn) {
  if (!(nn%%1==0) | (nn<1)){
    return(0)
  } 
  my.fib <- c(1,1)
  for (kk in 3:nn){
    my.fib[kk] <- my.fib[kk-1] + my.fib[kk-2]
  }
  return(my.fib[nn])
}

fibonacci(7)   
fibonacci(5)   
fibonacci(1)   
fibonacci(1.5) 
fibonacci(0)
```

It prints everything correctly for 7,5,1.5 and 0, as it gives me the vaules 13, 5, 0, and 0. But when trying to print fibonacci(1), I get the error

```
Error in my.fib[kk] <- my.fib[kk - 1] + my.fib[kk - 2] : 
  replacement has length zero
```

I want to leave as much as the code the same as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `if` condition to check for `nn = 1`.

```
fibonacci <- function(nn) {
  if (!(nn%%1==0) | (nn<1)){
    return(0)
  } else if(nn == 1) return(1)
  my.fib <- c(1,1)
  for (kk in 3:nn){
    my.fib[kk] <- my.fib[kk-1] + my.fib[kk-2]
  }
  return(my.fib[nn])
}
```

Comment: When I do that, it returns 0, I need it to return 1.

Comment: Isn't the 1st value of Fibonacci sequence 0 ? I have updated the answer to return 1 anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! I thought my error was in the for loop.